# How to fix 'The "fb:pages" tag on the URL doesn't contain this Page's ID.'

Tags: html, facebook

I got this error when I try to claim my site for facebook instant articles 'The "fb:pages" tag on the URL doesn't contain this Page's ID. Please work with your developers/webmaster to add this tag to your website.'

I have already included the meta tag inside of  in my HTML file.
And the ID is correct.

Comment: What URL is it?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Answer (score 0):

if you are using wordpress you can reset wp and try again.